# How could I change generic class parameter that has been specified at super class from subclass?

Tags: java, generics, subclass

```
public class Class2 extends Class1<A, B>{}

public class Class3 extends Class2{}
```

In Class3,  I wanna change the B to C, is it possible ?
Thanks!

Comment: No.  If you want to do that, make `Class2` generic as well.

Answer (score 0):

```
public class Class2<B> extends Class1<A, B>{}

public class Class3<C> extends Class2<C>{}
```

Thats one way, then again.. it would be better to just extend Class3 from Class1 and change it.

```
public class Class2 extends Class1<A, B>{}

public class Class3 extends Class1<A, C>{}
```

Comment: Why would that be better?

Comment: Cause then he wouldnt have to make class2 generic just for that

Comment: Sure, but now `Class3` instances won't be assignable to `Class2` references, so the semantics of the code have changed.

Comment: True, but thats what interfaces are for, you dont have to inherit everything to achieve polymorphism.

edit: But since we dont know the full design, everything we say is pretty much a theory lol.

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply.  The reason for extending Class2 is reusing some common code in Class2. And in my situation B is a view class, i wanna change the view B in Class3 and reuse the common code in Class2 at same time.

Comment: Then making Class2 generic is how you would be able to change B for C depending on which class extends it. :) Though you might want to consider using composition instead of inheritance for code reuse. Sometimes, it avoids complex hierarchies.

Comment: OK, i will consider it.  The question is the common code is some template method of system, such as onCreate,onStart in Android. Maybe the goal of my question is impossible  to ahcieve in Java ....